# Deny scroll to first position in recyclerview

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, recyclerview-layout

I have recycler view with adapter. Need deny user to scroll to item with 0 index, when it was scrolled. F.e user scrolls to 5 item and when scrolls back first visible will be item with index 1.
Will be glad any ideas how to implement this feature.

Comment: Check my answer below.It will suffice your need

Comment: I think the best way to handle this is by removing the item at index 0 (the one you don't want to display it and then put it back to the same location when needed.. this will help you avoid hacking your way around the user interaction

Comment: Its to easy remove 0 item, but I cannot notify adapter because of many some issues, connected with notify and own custom layout manager.

Answer (score 0):

Use `smoothScrollToIndex(1)` inside `addOnScrollListener` of the recycler view.
Keep a if check with `!recyclerView.canScrollVertically(-1)` there if it succeeded then use like :

```
 mRecyclerView.addOnScrollListener(new RecyclerView.OnScrollListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onScrolled(RecyclerView recyclerView, int dx, int dy) {

                            super.onScrolled(recyclerView, dx, dy); 
                            if(!recyclerView.canScrollVertically(-1))
                             {
                              mRecyclerView.smoothScrollToIndex(1);
                             }
                    }});
```